# Link to force download of external image with Python web app

Tags: python, download, imagedownload

I've got a Python (Wep2py) web app that generates QR codes using the Google chart API. The app displays the QR code on the screen, and I want to offer a link to download it. Considering the images are not on my server, what are my options?

**Example image url:**
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=Hello%20world

**EDIT:**

I've seen mention of using the header `Content-disposition: attachment;` to force a download dialog. Does anyone know if this header can be applied to external resources?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="https://chart......world">Download QR code here</a>
```

**Edit:** If the browser of your user is able to handle the mimetype Google sends for the image, the browser will handle it. There is not much you can do about this which is a Good Thing<sup>TM</sup>.

Comment: That shows the image in a new tab- any way to force a download?

Comment: In a new tab? Well, then people can save it, can't they? Why force them if the browser can display the image?

Comment: It's for users that don't necessarily know about right-clicking. The download link is supposed to initiate a download dialog. See my edits.